Как делать массовый import в python
Я новичок в python, и у меня в ходе наработки практики возник один сложный для моего понимания вопрос. Я делаю мини-проект на фрейме PyQt : есть главный файл .py, который отражает загрузку основного меню, и несколько файлов .py, в которых описана логика работы дополнительных окон на которые ссылается основной файл.
Вопрос в следующем: я понимаю, как подключить дополнительные файлы к основному файлу, и всё работает. Но меня смущает, что внутри каждого файла есть импорт одной и той же библиотеки PyQt6. Не нагружает ли это систему и является ли корректным написанием кода? Мне кажется, что нет, и я хотел бы это исправить и понять, как правильно.
Например, каждый файл содержит строчку: from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QDialog.
Она есть и в основном файле и во всех дополнительных, которые привязаны к основному. Возможно ли сделать импорт данного модуля в основной файл и передавать его в дополнительные? Как это можно сделать? И как будет правильно?

Не нагружает, ничего делать не надо

@andreymal подскажите пожалуйста, то есть это правильный способ написания кода?

При импорте проверяется, если модуль уже загружен, то он второй раз не загружается. Эта проверка быстрая - буквально ключ в словаре проверить. Так что пишите все нужные данному конкретному скрипту импорты и не парьтесь, что они где-то будут повторяться.

@CrazyElf огромное спасибо за подобные ответы, они очень мне ценны. Даже после того, как потом всё это будет собрано в exe?

@Bucket Я насчёт сборки в .exe у меня опыта нет, но видимо да, разницы нет. Кстати, при сборке в .exe все нестандартные модули обычно отдельным параметром сборщику передаются, я так понимаю, там вообще без разницы, где они подключаются, сборщик их один раз соберёт, как в его конфиге прописано. Как-то так.
